# Whats the best way to plot geohash values?

Tags: elasticsearch, d3.js, kibana, vega

I am using elasticsearch as my data source and aggregating on lat/lon to get geohash values and corresponding doc_counts. What would be the best way to plot it on a geo map.

I am trying to use Vega with Kibana, but other solutions welcome.

My query:

```
    GET index*/_search?size=0
    {
      "aggs" : {
        "large-grid" : {
          "geohash_grid" : {
            "field" : "geoip.location",
              "precision" : 3
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Results:

```
    "aggregations" : {
        "large-grid" : {
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : "9yd",
              "doc_count" : 6628672
            },
            {
              "key" : "9qh",
              "doc_count" : 1546684
            },
            {
              "key" : "9tb",
              "doc_count" : 1502557
            },
            {
              "key" : "dp3",
              "doc_count" : 1499205
            },
```

Comment: It would help to be more specific or provide additional data. Do have different aggregations depending on zoom level? Do you want the hashes to be represented by points, by areas, or by clusters of points? Why is simply [converting](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geohash.html) the hash to a lat/long pair or bounding box insufficient?

Comment: Ideally what i am wanting to do is plot count(aggregated per day/hour) of documents per lat/lon, i decided to use geohash. But then geohash needs to reverted back to lat/lon. (there is no way to retain lat/lon after aggregation on es).

Comment: So is it sufficient to take the hash and produce a lat/long pair? Plotting then should be straight forward if there is no need for any clustering after the fact (as points represent aggregated counts already).

Comment: yes. that should work. But if there was a way I could do that with vega, would be simple for my use case.

Comment: Hi, perhaps the first decision is about the use of geographical map (see LeafletJS.com) as background, or not in your data visualization.

Comment: Solution for this abandoned question: https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-es-geohashgrid